# Android webview: нет доступа к микрофону

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

Я хочу воспользоваться компонентом `WebView` для создания sip-клиента (у меня уже есть десктоп-версия на Electron + библиотека SipMl5).

Я предоставил разрешения на микрофон, который мне нужен для звонков:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.angiga.ansipml">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Также я разрешил выполнение JS:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mybrowser.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    mybrowser.settings.domStorageEnabled = true


    //mybrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
    //mybrowser.loadUrl("https://html5test.com/")
    mybrowser.loadUrl("https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/volume/")
}
```

Однако при попытке воспользоваться приложением, в консоли появляется ошибка

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:adm_helpers.cc(73)] Failed to query stereo recording.
```

При этом в тестах WebRtc получаю ошибку `navigator.getUserMedia error`

Получается, что у приложения доступ к микрофону есть, а `WebView` - нет.

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Из самого webview не получиться. Надо делать мосты в натив.

Comment: @Nik Насколько, я понял, начиная с пятого андроида webview это, фактически, хром, а в хроме доступ к микрофону работает.